# Save and retrieve content of req.session

Tags: node.js, express, express-session

I've searched other questions but none seems to help me. I'm trying to save the parameters of a search in a table in angularJs, using the express-session module.
I already save some info in session when the user log in (and it worked fine). But when I try to do the same with filters, it doesn't work

This is what I use

In server.js

```
var session = require('express-session');
var passport = require('passport');
var app = express();

app.use(session({ 
   secret: 'secret' ,
   saveUninitialized: true,
   resave: true, 
}));
```

In AngularJs I call the function to set and retrieve session data

Retrieve data

```
$http.get(apihost + '/customSessionFilters/getSessionFilters')
   .success(function (getCurrentFilters) {

       if(getCurrentFilters.status == 'filters') {
           console.log(getCurrentFilters);
       }
       else {
           console.log('no filters');
       }
   })
   .error(function (err) {
       Notification.error(err.message);
   });
```

Set data

```
var filters = angular.toJson($scope.searchParams);
$http.post(apihost + '/customSessionFilters/setSessionFilters/' + filters)
 .success(function (setCurrentFilters) {
    console.log(setCurrentFilters);
    })
     .error(function (err) {
         Notification.error(err.message);
    });
```

And then the 2 functions in nodejs

Set Data

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var session = require('express-session');

router.post('/setSessionFilters/:paramsFilter',function(req,res,next) {

    var filters = JSON.parse(req.params.paramsFilter);

    req.session.customSessionFilters = filters;

    console.log('PROVA NUOVO SERVICE -> setSessionFilters');
    console.log(req.session);

    res.json({status: 'ok', data: req.session.customSessionFilters});
});
```

And retrieve data

```
router.get('/getSessionFilters',function(req,res,next) {

    console.log('***********');
    console.log(req.session);

    if(req.session.customSessionFilters) {
        console.log('PROVA NUOVO SERVICE -> getSessionFilters');
        console.log(req.session.customSessionFilters);

        res.json({status: 'filters', data: req.session.customSessionFilters});
    }
    else {
        console.log('PROVA NUOVO SERVICE -> no filters');

        res.json({status: 'no_filters'});
    }
});
```

I expect to find the req.session.customSessionFilters to be filled with the parameters i set in the search form in the table. I know that data are passed to the "Set session data" cause I can see them in the console.log, but when I reach the "Get session data", they just disappear. 
Any help?

Edit:
output of router.post(customSessionFilters/setSessionFilters)(UserMaintenanceCenterCode and dealerList are the variabile I already put in session in the login; customSessionFilters is what I add in the function)

```
Session {
    cookie:
    { path: '/',
        _expires: null,
        originalMaxAge: null,
        httpOnly: true },
    passport: { user: 90 },
    UserMaintenanceCenterCode: [ 1 ],
    dealerList: [ 13 ],
    customSessionFilters: { year: 2018, Code: 'CC010', Dealer: 13 } 
}
```

Output of router.get(customSessionFilters/getSessionFilters) is the same, but without customSessionFilters.

Output of $http.post(apihost + '/customSessionFilters/setSessionFilters') is not showed, but it would just print the customSessionFilters in the connected function.

Output of $http.get(apihost + '/customSessionFilters/getSessionFilters') always print "no_filters" (the response from the function when customSessionFilters is not defined)

Comment: What is the `console.log` output and response of  `'/customSessionFilters/getSessionFilters'` and `'/customSessionFilters/setSessionFilters/...'`

Comment: Have you tried `resave: false` in the express-session ?

Comment: Oh my, that worked! Wow, I didn't think that could be different (I already used it in the login and I didn't have to change it)....well, thank you very much! :D